# Why is modifying a Ruby string in-place so slow?

Tags: ruby

I'm curious if somebody can explain why modifying a Ruby string in-place is so slow.  Consider changing the x's in a long string to y's.  Here's one way:

```
s = "x"*1000000
s = s.chars.map {|c| c == "x" ? "y" : c }.join
```

And another:

```
s = "x"*1000000
s = (0...s.length).map {|i| s[i] == "x" ? "y" : s[i] }.join
```

These both finish in <0.25 seconds.  Now consider:

```
s = "x"*1000000
(0...s.length).each do |i|
  s[i] = "y" if s[i] == "x"
end
```

This takes 60 seconds, an increase factor of 250x.

Please do NOT, repeat, do NOT answer that there are faster ways of changing x's to y's using Regexp, or String#gsub, or String#tr, or whatever.  That's not the question.  This is an abstraction of a larger, complex computation.  The question is, it would seem to be faster to modify a string in-place than to break a string into an array of strings, create a new array of strings, and join those back together.  Yet it's not.

Further, this behavior is not seen with, say arrays of integers.  Using the third approach on an array of integers is just as fast as the first two approaches.  It seems peculiar to strings.

Comment: Forgot to add, I'm using Ruby 2.3.7.

Comment: Cannot confirm. On my system (with Ruby 2.7.0) the last method is actually the fastest of all three.

Comment: BTW, [even Ruby 2.4 is no longer supported](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2020/04/05/support-of-ruby-2-4-has-ended/)

Comment: You should include details on how you're benchmarking. Benchmarking can be tricky and misleading if you're not careful.

Comment: Wow, I was able to run under Ruby 2.7.0 and agree, all three versions are comparably fast.  Clearly the behavior I described is specific to an older version of Ruby, so... it's not a very interesting question.  Sorry for the noise, but thanks for the pointer.

Comment: "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)"
will probably be useful reading.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'fruity'

3.times do
  compare do
    t1 do
      s = 'x' * 100_000
      s.chars.map { |c| c == 'x' ? 'y' : c }.join
    end

    t2 do
      s = 'x' * 100_000
      (0...s.length).map { |i| s[i] == 'x' ? 'y' : s[i] }.join
    end

    t3 do
      s = 'x' * 100_000
      (0...s.length).each do |i|
        s[i] = 'y' if s[i] == 'x'
      end
      s
    end
  end
  puts '-' * 5
end
```

```
# >> Running each test once. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> t1 is faster than t2 by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
# >> t2 is faster than t3 by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
# >> -----
# >> Running each test once. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> t1 is faster than t2 by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
# >> t2 is faster than t3 by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
# >> -----
# >> Running each test once. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> t1 is similar to t2
# >> t2 is similar to t3
# >> -----
```

```
require 'benchmark'

puts 'Ruby %s' % RUBY_VERSION

3.times do
  Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
    s = 'x' * 100_000
    x.report("t1")  { 
      s.chars.map { |c| c == 'x' ? 'y' : c }.join 
    }

    s = 'x' * 100_000
    x.report("t2")  { 
      (0...s.length).map { |i| s[i] == 'x' ? 'y' : s[i] }.join 
    }

    s = 'x' * 100_000
    x.report("t3")  { 
      (0...s.length).each do |i|
        s[i] = 'y' if s[i] == 'x'
      end  
    }
  end
  puts "\n" * 2
end
```

```
# >> Ruby 2.7.1
# >> Rehearsal --------------------------------------
# >> t1   0.038257   0.002995   0.041252 (  0.041296)
# >> t2   0.032536   0.000467   0.033003 (  0.033034)
# >> t3   0.030509   0.000018   0.030527 (  0.030539)
# >> ----------------------------- total: 0.104782sec
# >> 
# >>          user     system      total        real
# >> t1   0.019340   0.000012   0.019352 (  0.019354)
# >> t2   0.040595   0.000228   0.040823 (  0.040834)
# >> t3   0.017477   0.000118   0.017595 (  0.017603)
# >> 
# >> 
# >> Rehearsal --------------------------------------
# >> t1   0.032491   0.001619   0.034110 (  0.034195)
# >> t2   0.032207   0.000259   0.032466 (  0.032531)
# >> t3   0.030463   0.000145   0.030608 (  0.030631)
# >> ----------------------------- total: 0.097184sec
# >> 
# >>          user     system      total        real
# >> t1   0.019730   0.000011   0.019741 (  0.019743)
# >> t2   0.043388   0.000212   0.043600 (  0.043639)
# >> t3   0.016638   0.000009   0.016647 (  0.016647)
# >> 
# >> 
# >> Rehearsal --------------------------------------
# >> t1   0.030882   0.000480   0.031362 (  0.031434)
# >> t2   0.030787   0.000647   0.031434 (  0.031444)
# >> t3   0.026310   0.000009   0.026319 (  0.026320)
# >> ----------------------------- total: 0.089115sec
# >> 
# >>          user     system      total        real
# >> t1   0.015613   0.000004   0.015617 (  0.015618)
# >> t2   0.037264   0.000367   0.037631 (  0.037699)
# >> t3   0.016907   0.000097   0.017004 (  0.017003)
```